# How do I create a routes.rb entry for a controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I'm trying to populate an iframe with some erb and I can't figure out how to create a route to the new controller.

```
class TestController < ApplicationController
  def iframe
    load_channels
    render :partial => "report", :layout => "test"
  end
end
```

This is in my webpage:

```
<iframe src="<%= url_for controller: 'test', action: 'iframe' %>" name="report"></iframe>"
```

I created a layout with basic html and erb.

I'm getting "no route matches" error. When I look at the routes.rb file it's one of the most confusing config files that I've ever seen.

How do I route to this controller?

Comment: this probably can help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/11352918/938947

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to put `get ‘htmlfilename’, to:’test#iframe’`in the routes.rb and see if it works. The htmlfilename should be without the extension. And in the url_for you can put the **path** rather than `controller: 'test', action: 'iframe'`. For more information you can check the Rails [routing documentation here](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html).

Comment: I guess I get a little stuck on the "resource" keyword. The routes.rb that I have is probably out of the norm. I believe the "get" and "to" need to be in a loop with an "end" but what would the header line be? The documentation is a little confusing for this case. Thx.